# Open new blank page when click listview

Tags: list, listview, view, android-activity

I'm new to android and I just made a List. When you click an listview item it should open a new page, lets say the standard "Hello world" Page. But I don't know how to create this.

Mainactivity.java

```
package pcsalt.example.customlistviewdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

ListView lvDetail;
Context context = MainActivity.this;
ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();

String[] title = new String[] {
        "Above & Beyond", "Afrojack", "DJ 3", "DJ 4",
        "DJ 5", "DJ 6", "DJ 7", "DJ 8"
};
String[] desc  = new String[] {
        "56:58", "58:49", "60:00", "60:00",
        "60:00", "60:00", "60:00", "60:00"
};
int[]    img   = new int[]    {
        R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star3,
        R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star3, R.drawable.star8
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    lvDetail = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCustomList);
    // insert data into the list before setting the adapter
    // otherwise it will generate NullPointerException  - Obviously
    getDataInList();
    lvDetail.setAdapter(new MyBaseAdapter(context, myList));
}

private void getDataInList() {
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {
        // Create a new object for each list item
        ListData ld = new ListData();
        ld.setTitle(title[i]);
        ld.setDescription(desc[i]);
        ld.setImgResId(img[i]);
        // Add this object into the ArrayList myList
        myList.add(ld);
    }

}
```

}

Can you please explain specific what I need to add? (Also new xml/java files).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
lvDetail.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.putExtra("position", arg2+"");

            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```

Comment: When I click an item the app crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you added the Activity to your Manifest.

Then add this to the Answer above: Intent i = new Intent(**MainActivity.this, NewActivity.class**)